# Can a scrollviewer be added to a relative panel?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, scrollviewer

Is it possible to add a scrollviewer to relative panel in UWP? I tried and it does not seem to be working at all. I need the scrollviewer to make sure all the controls on the screen are shown when i change the orientation of the phone.

Comment: I add a scrollviewer in relative panel, it can scroll in Vertical and Horizontal. So if you have some issue. Please post you code.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same situation, what I did may helps you,
I put `RelativePanel` inside `ScrollViewer` and your `ScrollViewer` will be in a `Grid`. `VisualStateManager` thing will come in Grid not in `RelativePanel`.
Like below :

```
<Grid>
  <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
      ...
  </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

  <ScrollViewer>
     <RelativePanel>
        ...
     </RelativePanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```